# Why Chrome sometimes makes 2 AJAX requests instead of 1?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

I have encountered a strange behaviour of current version of Google Chrome (44.0.2403.157) on OS X.

When I do AJAX (XHR) request with method GET with my Chrome *sometimes* makes 1 request and sometimes - 2 (!).

My code:

```
var jsUrl = 'http://www.some-domain.com/xy.js';

var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.withCredentials = true;
  ajax.open( 'GET', jsUrl, true ); // async, because sync cannot be send with cookies
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
      var script = ajax.response || ajax.responseText;
      if (ajax.readyState === 4) {
          switch( ajax.status) {
              case 200:
              case 304:
                eval.apply( window, [script] );
                // no break on purpose here
              default:
                someFunction();
          }
      }
  };
  ajax.send(null);
```

A screenshot of my developer console when 2 requests are being made:

[image: my developer console showing 2 requests]

Server log confirms that the second request is being made - it's not just in the console.

The headers of the second request are practically the same as the first one - the only difference is the value of the cookie that is being changed with the 3rd request on the screen above.

Note that current version of Firefox (40.0.3) on OS X **doesn't** show this behaviour - only 1 request is made here, every time (tested by both watching request using Firebug (with BFCache requests shown) and by watching the server logs).

For a while I thought that using `send()` vs `send(null)` makes a difference - that when using `send()` only one request is being made - but after more tests I see that the strangeness is present with both syntaxes.

**Can you give me a hint about what is happening here?**

Comment: If this is indeed happening then I think it would be a chrome bug.  I'd use a packet analyzer to confirm--it seems kind of hard to believe.

Comment: I don't think that I need to use packet analyzer when I confirmed that double requests are being made by looking at the server logs, @dave. Or do you think that I will see more there?

Comment: I think it's worth checking,  since it's such a strange issue.